# What is $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6+3}}{x^3-1}\;$?

Tags: limits, analysis

I need some help. I need to evaluate the following:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6+3}}{x^3-1}$$
Here is what I have so far...
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6+3}}{x^3-1} = \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6\big(1+\frac{3}{x^6}\big)}}{x^3\big(1-\frac{1}{x^3}\big)} = \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x^6}}}{1-\frac{1}{x^3}} = \frac{\sqrt{1}}{1} = 1.
\end{align*}

I thought I was correct, but on online calculators, they say the answer is actually -1. How did they get this?

Comment: Since x approches negative infinity x is negative so you need the abolute value too

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is the first time I have had to consider the absolute value in a square root, but it makes sense in this case. Kind of amazing how I have never encountered that this far in my math program.

Comment: You're very welcome 
Dillan Marroquin.

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6+3}}{x^3-1} $$
$$L= \lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6\big(1+\frac{3}{x^6}\big)}}{x^3\big(1-\frac{1}{x^3}\big)}$$
$$L=\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} |x^3| \frac{\sqrt{\big(1+\frac{3}{x^6}\big)}}{x^3\big(1-\frac{1}{x^3}\big)} $$
Then $|x^3|=-x^3$ since $x$ approaches $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is almost right, indeed we have that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ and then your intermediate step should be
$$ \frac{\sqrt{x^6\big(1+\frac{3}{x^6}\big)}}{x^3\big(1-\frac{1}{x^3}\big)} = \frac{|x^3|\sqrt{\big(1+\frac{3}{x^6}\big)}}{x^3\big(1-\frac{1}{x^3}\big)}$$

which leads to the correct result.